# Undefined is not an object - When attempting to access json object

Tags: javascript

I'm currently attempting to use the Flickr API and javascript to generate a page based on a search query, in this case, dogs. When the line

```
var hyperLink = "https://www.flickr.com/photos/" + photo.owner + "/" + photo.id + ".jpg";
```

Runs it states undefined is not an object in regards to photo.owner. I am able to print out photo.owner using console.log(photo.owner) but cannot access it to merely print out the information in the url.

Full code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>The Flickr Experiment</title>
</head>
<body id ="1">


<script>
    function jsonFlickrApi(rsp) {
        var str = "";
        str +="<h1>Doggo piccies from Flickr</h1>"; 
        str +="<h3>Total piccies: " + rsp.photos.photo.length;
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i <= rsp.photos.photo.length; i++) { 
        var photo = rsp.photos.photo[i];
        var imageTitle = photo.title;
        var hyperLink = "https://www.flickr.com/photos/" + photo.owner + "/" + photo.id + ".jpg";
        var imgLink = "https://farm" + photo.farm + ".staticflickr.com/" + photo.server + "/" + photo.id + "_" + photo.secret + "_t.jpg";
        str +="<a href=\"" + hyperLink + "\"><img alt=\"" + imageTitle + "\" src=\"" + imgLink + "\"/></a>"
        }

        document.writeln(str);
    }
</script>


<script src="https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=XXXXf&tags=golden-retriever&per_page=100&format=json">
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Debug your code. Step through it in a debugger, examining the value of variables. SO is not a human-powered remote debugging service.

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling I'm really glad it was as simple as the <= causing it, I've been pulling hair for a couple of days now. I assumed that it was failing to retrieve the object on the first pass and was very confused. I had tried many object/accessing data solutions but had not considered it was caused by my loop.

I'm pretty used to debugging Java but am still learning Chrome/Safari's debugging tools so I'll keep this in mind for next time!

Comment: @torazaburo This is the first time I've ever posted to SO, normally I can find my answers in past responses / googling but this one stumped me. Thank you for your warm welcome to the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are zero based. That means if an array's length is 3, then the highest index is 2. The loop condition must therefore be

```
i < rsp.photos.photo.length
//^^ strictly smaller, not smaller or equal
```

If not, you will be accessing an index (namely the length of the array) which doesn't exist, which will result in `undefined`, the error you are getting.

Simple example:

```js
var arr = [1,2,3];
console.log(arr[0]);
console.log(arr[1]);
console.log(arr[2]);
console.log(arr[arr.length]);
```